# How to save an entire array in a slot of a multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there any way to do the following?

```
int[,] multiArray = new int[5,5];

multiArray[0] = {0, 1, 3, 4, 5};
```

Comment: use jagged arrays `int[][] multiArray = new int[5][]; multiArray[0] = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, with multidimensional arrays, this is not possible. The array has a fixed size, and the compiler does not now what size you are allowed to assign to the array.

Also, how would the compiler know if you meant to do this:

```
multiArray[0, 0..4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

or this:

```
multiArray[0..4, 0] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

However, you can use jagged arrays:

```
int[][] multiArray = new int[5][];
multiArray[0] = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Comment: -1: This is possible. Not particularly clean, but definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is save each element of the array into the same row but DIFFERENT columns of the multiArray.

```
multiArray[0][0] = 0;
multiArray[0][1] = 1;
multiArray[0][2] = 2;
multiArray[0][3] = 3;
multiArray[0][4] = 4;
multiArray[0][5] = 5;
```

I believe that is what you're trying to do. You can simplify this with a for loop as well.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to assign each slot individually like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET multidimensional arrays are stored in row-major order, you can use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) for this operation (filling a full row at a time). Note the use of `sizeof(int)` since this method operates on *bytes*, not elements (unlike methods such as `Array.Copy`).

```
int[,] multiArray = new int[5, 5];

int rowIndex = 0;
int[] rowData = { 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 };

int destOffset = rowIndex * sizeof(int) * multiArray.GetLength(0);
Buffer.BlockCopy(rowData, 0, multiArray, destOffset, rowData.Length * sizeof(int));
```